# Imagemagick GIF Dimensions Repeat Over and Over

Tags: python, imagemagick, subprocess, imagemagick-convert

I am using Imagemagick identify in a Python script to determine an image's dimensions. When analyzing animated GIFs, the dimensions repeat again and again, e.g. `500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375`.

Why is this happening? How can I clean up this output into a simple width / height?

The Python script that produces this result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess, logging

# identify -ping -format "%w %h" test.gif
dimensions = subprocess.check_output([
    r'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.3-Q16\identify.exe',
    '-ping',
    '-format',
    '%w %h',
    "../www/content/test.gif"
])

# b string to utf-8 string
dimensions = dimensions.decode("utf-8")

logging.warning(dimensions)
```

And the output in the log is as follows:

```
WARNING:root:500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375500 375
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

The comment on this answer is correct - the best way is to use `image.gif[0]`.

**Original Answer**

The dimensions are repeated again and again because the animated gif has multiple frames. I figured it out when I noticed that each gif's dimensions were repeated different numbers of times.

I changed '%w %h' to '%w %h;' and used split to isolate the first frame.

```
dimensions = dimensions.decode("utf-8").split(';') #375 500
```

Comment: You could just use `image.gif[0]` to identify/isolate the dimensions of the first frame.